# Unable to stop method execution with timeout exception in nest js

Tags: nest

I have a nest api with one endpoint. I want to throw a RequestTimeoutException() if the app hasn't responded within 60 seconds, and also stop the execution of the method called without stopping the program itself. I am able to throw the exception to the client, but the app continues with the execution even though an exception has already been thrown.

I've tried the following:

1. Using an interceptor: this allows to throw an exception to the client, but does not stop the execution of the method called.

```
@Injectable()
export class TimeoutInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
  intercept(context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler): Observable<any> {
    return next.handle().pipe(
      timeout(60000),
      catchError((err) => {
        if (err instanceof TimeoutError) {
          return throwError(() => new RequestTimeoutException());
        }
        return throwError(() => err);
      }),
    );
  }
}
```

```
@Controller('chatbot')
@UseInterceptors(TimeoutInterceptor)
export class ChatbotController {
  private readonly chatbotService = new ChatbotService();

  @Post('query')
  async postQuery(@Body() body: QueryModel) {
    if (
      !body.chatInfo ||
      !body.chatInfo.chatId ||
      !body.chatInfo.userId ||
      !body.question
    )
      throw new BadRequestException();

    const response = await this.chatbotService.generateResponse(body);

    return response;
  }
}
```

2. Using a timeout: this stops the execution of the program.

```
@Post('query')
  async postQuery(@Body() body: QueryModel) {
    let timeoutHandler: NodeJS.Timeout
    try {
      timeoutHandler = setTimeout(() => {
        throw new RequestTimeoutException()
      }, 60000)

      if (
        !body.chatInfo ||
        !body.chatInfo.chatId ||
        !body.chatInfo.userId ||
        !body.question
      )
        throw new BadRequestException();
  
      const response = await this.chatbotService.generateResponse(body);
      
      clearTimeout(timeoutHandler)
      return response;
    } catch (error) {
      clearTimeout(timeoutHandler)
      throw error;  // or return error;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should define a AbortController and pass it to the generateResponse method and after 60000 seconds abort the controller, it should be something like this:

```
@Controller('chatbot')
@UseInterceptors(TimeoutInterceptor)
export class ChatbotController {
  private readonly chatbotService = new ChatbotService();

  @Post('query')
  async postQuery(@Body() body: QueryModel) {
    if (!body.chatInfo !body.chatInfo.chatId !body.chatInfo.userId !body.question) {
      throw new BadRequestException();
    }

    const controller = new AbortController(); 
    const signal = controller.signal;  

    let timeoutHandler: NodeJS.Timeout = setTimeout(() => {
      controller.abort();  
    }, 60000);

    try {
      const response = await this.chatbotService.generateResponse(body, signal);
      clearTimeout(timeoutHandler);
      return response;
    } catch (error) {
      clearTimeout(timeoutHandler);
      if (signal.aborted) {
        throw new RequestTimeoutException();
      }
      throw error;
    }
  }
}
```

and the service:

```
@Injectable()
export class ChatbotService {
  async generateResponse(body: QueryModel, signal?: AbortSignal): Promise<any> {
    if (signal?.aborted) {
      throw new RequestTimeoutException();
    }
  }
}
```